# Find longest substring not working for a particular test case in c++

Tags: c++, string, hashtable

Q) Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Given "abcabcbb", the answer is "abc", which the length is 3.

Given "bbbbb", the answer is "b", with the length of 1.

Given "pwwkew", the answer is "wke", with the length of 3. Note that the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a substring.

My answer :

```
class Solution {
public:
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    int count[256];
    int dummy=0;
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
        count[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        count[s[i]]++;
        if(count[s[i]]==1){
        c++;
        i++;
        //cout<<c;
        }
        else{
        //cout<<C;
        dummy=dummy>c?dummy:c;
        //cout<<dummy;
        c=0;
            for(int j=0;j<256;j++){
                count[j]=0;
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
     return dummy;
}
};
```

I know this is not an optimal solution but I am a rookie. This code worked for a lot of test cases except for the string "pwwkew" for which the original answer is 3 but I am getting 0.

What I have tried:

For the string `"abcabcbb"` I am getting the correct output which is 3.

For the string `"bbbb"` I am getting the correct output which is 1.

For the particular string `"pwwkew"` I am getting it as 0. The answer should have been 3 in this case.

I tried printing the values to check where I went wrong. For the third case it does not seem to enter the `else` statement. 
`cout` in the if statement prints `123`. But It should have printed `12` for `pw`. `cout` in the else statement does not work.

Why only for this case I am getting a wrong output?

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @immibis  I have updated my question. I really don't know why for this particular test case it doesn't work. It has 100 testcases. Mine passed 73/100 testcases. 74th testcase is the string "pwwkew".

Comment: What did you try to change you code's behaviour from *not producing the result required* to *producing the required result*?

Comment: @FeiXiang Sorry sir, I have now mentioned what I tried with print statements.

Comment: @greybeard I only wanted to know why this doesn't work so i wont repeat the same mistake again. I know there are better approaches but I am just curious.

Comment: fwiw Programming is not about _learning what mistakes to "not repeat"_. It's about understanding the state changes going on, the cause-and-effect, and figuring when&why it doesn't do as you expect. So with that said, do the following: Output `s[i]` on each iteration. Pay careful attention to the output for the `"abcabcbb"` test. You should find it "surprising" and it reveals that this case only works by accident. You also have a fundamental flaw in your algorithm that makes it impossible to return the longest sequence ending on the last character. These clues should help you.

Comment: As @CraigYoung pointed out your case works only by an accident. And apart from that you can initialize as int count[256] = {0};

Comment: You increment i twice in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is something wrong (or at least missing) in the algorithm of OP.

I didn't understand the algorithm completely but at least to a point that the occurrence of characters are counted. If `count` for a specific character is not `1` then a duplicate is found and `count` array is completely reset. IMHO this is the wrong point. The `count` array degenerates to a flag array (and this is not sufficient).

Counter example `pwwkwe`:

- duplicate at `s[2]`
- reset `count` (i.e. restart)
- duplicate at `s[4]`
- reset `count` (i.e. restart).

Hence, the longest detected substring would have at most length 2. But starting at `k` it is actually 3 (`kwe`).

So, I came up with a different idea:

Once, a duplicate is found the longest substring might actually start just behind the previous occurence of this character. Considering this, the duplicate is not anymore a duplicate.

This may sound a bit confusing. May be, it becomes easier to understand when I show how I solved it:

`count` isn't used as flags array anymore. Instead, the index of last occurrence is stored there (for each character). So, for each character, the distance to its previous occurrence can be checked (which is free of duplicates of this character). But, it must be free of any duplicate. Therefore, I introduced additionally a start index (`i0`) which is always set once behind a previous occurrence of a character. (Duplicates before start index are not considered.) This way, only the last duplicate is considered when determining a proper substring.

In code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/* determines longest substring without duplicated characters.
 * param s ... string to evaluate
 * return: pair of
 *   first  ... start index of found substring
 *   second ... length of found substring
 */
std::pair<int, int> lengthOfLongestSubstring(const std::string &s)
{
  // index of last occurrence for each character
  // (-1 ... character not yet occurred)
  int iChrLast[256];
  for (int &i : iChrLast) i = -1;
  // result start index, length
  std::pair<int, int> result(0, 0);
  // check all characters (i0 ... current start)
  for (int i = 0, i0 = 0; i < (int)s.length(); ++i) {
    // cast char to index (via (unsigned char) to prevent negative indices)
    const int c = (unsigned char)s[i];
    // check if there is a duplicate after current start
    if (iChrLast[c] >= i0) i0 = iChrLast[c] + 1;
    // compute length with current start
    const int len = i - i0 + 1;
    // check whether new max. length found (update in case)
    if (result.second < len) result = std::make_pair(i0, len);
    // remember last occurrence of this char
    iChrLast[c] = i;
  }
  // done
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  const std::string tests[] = {
    "abcabcbb",
    "bbbbb",
    "pwwkew"
  };
  for (const std::string &test : tests) {
    const std::pair<int, int> result = lengthOfLongestSubstring(test);
    std::cout << test << ": " << result.first << ", " << result.second
      << " ("<< test.substr(result.first, result.second) << ")\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abcabcbb: 0, 3 (abc)
bbbbb: 0, 1 (b)
pwwkew: 2, 3 (wke)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61d5fc3682efdfbc)</kbd>

---

I have to admit that I agree with Craig Young that

> Programming is not about learning what mistakes to "not repeat". It's about understanding the state changes going on, the cause-and-effect, and figuring when & why it doesn't do as you expect.

I tried to solve this (as a puzzle) assuming that some kind of back-tracking or even recursion would be necessary. So, I was surprised myself a bit when I found this solution, finally. (And once I got it running I couldn't resist to post this as answer.)

How do you learn to make algorithms? May be, talent, may be, experience, and surely lots of practice...